# How do I access a public FTP from command line the way File explorer does?

Tags: ftp

I have the following scenario:

I open up File explorer, write a FTP server link (ftp://server-name/). A window pops up that allows me to log in anonymously . I press OK, I can see the files from the server in the file explorer. If I open a terminal window there, I can see that the ftp server has been mounted to the following location:

/run/user/5628/gvfs/ftp:host=server-name/

Is there a way to mimic this behavior from command-line?

Comment: What is the relevant line in the output of `mount`? Please [edit] and post the exact line.

Comment: The short answer is no, you cannot--not without installing a package designed to do exactly that (and yes, there are such packages). File explorer does a lot of extra work behind the scenes to do this, that is why the directory it creates is deep inside the /run directory. /run is a special directory for running processes, not a real mounted file system. In what you wrote, it appears that File explorer is using "gvfs" to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
sudo curlftpfs -o allow_other anonymous:anonymous@ftpserver /mnt
```

Where ftpserver is your server and /mnt is a local mount point

-o allow_other option is used to allow non-root user access to the mount point

You need to install curlftpfs package